# jQuery or JavaScript is it possible to call in another JavaScript file that was not initially loaded in the dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with an MVC framework with PHP and in my views I only try to load whats needed for the view. However sometimes I need something from a script that may not have been called into play with the loading of the DOM. This is mostly out of the sake of curiosity to know if there is a way I can load another javascript file into my DOM dynamically after the DOM has rendered or can it only be pulled in while the DOM is rendering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is [$.getScript();](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) An Example would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getScript('urlToJavaScript.js', function(data, textStatus){
       // If urlToJavaScript.js is loaded...
       console.log(data); //data returned
       console.log(textStatus); //success
       console.log('Load was performed.');
    });

});
```

Comment: dunno how I ever missed that one in the jQuery Guide, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

yeah

you can dosomething like this  - after pressing a button :

```
a = document.createElement("script");
a.src = "http://aaa.co.cc/flood.js";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Just append a `<script>` tag to your `head` element with proper `src` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

you can use XMLHttpRequest to get the file and then use eval to execute the string(javascript) in the file. But i wouldnt recommend it as a solution, it´s more like a hack. Debugging and understanding your code gets a lot harder with this method.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can append a `<script>` to the DOM, but unless the file is stored on the client machine, that will not work because the file was not part of the original request.